# How do I write a go Test function for something that reads from stdin?

Tags: go, testing, mocking, stdin

I have go test code similar to this:

```
func TestRollback(t *testing.T) {

  store := NewStore()
  
  // do some stuff

  err := store.Rollback()
  
  // checks
}
```

The problem is store.Rollback() has a prompt read from the stdin for y or n

How do I send "y" to the test process when running `go test -v --run TestRollback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can redirect stdin temporarily.

```
rd,wr,err := os.Pipe()
saved := os.Stdin
os.Stdin = rd

... Test code feeds wr ...

os.Stdin = saved
```

Comment: Although this works I decided I didn't like it for the reasons pointed out by the other answer.  So I modified the Rollback function to take bool which turns off the prompting.  I think this is much tidier.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty in testing your `Rollback` method stems from hardcoding its dependency on singleton `os.Stdin`.
[Tinkerer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68450149/2541573) is viable but, because it mutates that package-level variable, it doesn't lend itself to running tests in parallel.

A preferable alternative (IMO) consists in using an interface. Testing often rhymes with interface, in Go. Here, because `os.Stdin` satisfies the `io.Reader` interface, you could parameterise your `Store` type with an `io.Reader` passed to your factory function:

```
type Store struct {
  // other fields, omitted here
  in io.Reader
}

func NewStore(in io.Reader) *Store {
  store := Store {
    // other fields, omitted here
    in: in,
  }
  return &store
}
```

Then, in your test functions, you could use a concrete type that satisfies `io.Reader` and is easily configurable, such as a `*strings.Reader`:

```
func TestRollback(t *testing.T) {
  // arrange
  in := strings.Reader("-- put contents of stdin here --")
  store := NewStore(in)
  // act
  err := store.Rollback()
  // assert
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a reasonable suggestion.  But I decided to go in an alternative direction and just added a bool parameter to Rollback which skips the prompt and chooses "y" to proceed with the Rollback tasks.